# iOS Raw PixelFormat rggb has 2 channel?

Tags: image-processing, filter, avfoundation

I'm trying to get Raw pure data from avfoundation.

And I figured out that my device support pixelformat CV14BayerRggb.

After documentation, I got raw image file which is good.

However I want byte array from AVCapturephoto from photoOutput delegate callback.

There is one thing I can't not understand!!

When I look deep into pixelformatdescription of rggb,

```
<CVPixelBuffer 0x283b51ad0 width=4032 height=3024 bytesPerRow=8064 pixelFormat=rgg4 iosurface=0x280e59970 poolName=RENDERED_RAW attributes={
PixelFormatDescription =     {
    BitsPerBlock = 16;
    BitsPerComponent = 8;
    ContainsAlpha = 0;
    ContainsGrayscale = 0;
    ContainsRGB = 1;
    ContainsYCbCr = 0;
    FillExtendedPixelsCallback = {length = 24, bytes = 0x0000000000000000948536ba010000000000000000000000};
    PixelFormat = 1919379252;
};
```

Since after bayer filter, I know one pixel has one color data.
So using interpolation of neighboring pixels color data, fill up the other color value which is demosaicing.

But why in this moment, BitsPerBlock(BitsPerPixel) is 16?
Which is channel 2.

Is there anything I misunderstand about bayer filter?

Comment: I suppose it's one channel with 16 bits per pixel. [bitsPerComponent documentation] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454980-bitspercomponent) says *The number of bits used in memory for each color component of the specified bitmap image (or image mask). Possible values are 1, 2, 4, or 8.* so the value can't be 16. In case you want an answer (instead of a comment), please share a sample raw image to be used for verification (share using Google Drive for example).

Comment: @Rotem

Hi sorry for being late.
It is just raw image which I get from avphotooutput photocapture delegate callback.(set up for raw pixel format type)!

You want the image? then I will give u a link. 
is that gonna help u?

THANKS.

Comment: You are not doing me a favor... Do you still want an answer? Share an image, and I am willing to try answering (make sure that there are enough colors in the image so we can verify that the conversion to RGB is correct).

Comment: @Rotem
I didn't understand right what you are saying.
Alright, I'll give you a google drive link after I go back home.
By the way, thanks a lot :)